# Java File with all non public classes with one of them having a main method

Tags: java, class, classloader, access-modifiers

I just came across this weird scenario while playing :-)

Java's documentation specifies that a file can contain all non public classes and the file name not matching any of the class. When one tries to run after compilation it will generate Exception even after one of the classes having main method specified. Explanation is needed as to how to execute this file's main method.

My test code is as follows in file named **NoPublicClasses.java**:

```
class Class1{

}

class Class2{
public static void main(String[] args){

}

}
```

It compiles well. but if you try to run this it will throw exception. Below you can check what I tried

```
java NoPublicClasses
```

For the above I expected an Exception and it happened as I expected but when I did

```
java Class2
```

It also threw exception which was unexpected. So I need some kind person to explain the reason or if there's any solution to this issue without changing access modifier and file name or class name please let me know.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Mine runs when I call java class2.

Comment: could you please provide your `stacktrace`

Comment: @jeSuisBeau : Is there any public class in your file?

Comment: Nope. I'm using openjdk6. When I compile it, I get two classes, class1.class and class2.class. What do you get?

Comment: @jeSuisBeau: Did you use "public" access modifier in your code I am asking about that.

Comment: No. The only time public appears in my code is before static void main.

Comment: @jeSuisBeau: And it runs with OpenJDK as you are saying.

Comment: I get the same thing as you get but difference is that yours is running while mine is producing ClassNotFound for the first and Could not find main class for the second.

Comment: If your classes are declared as you have shown here, `java Class2` should run ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example should work normally. Make sure you are executing the correct class (i.e. don't confuse it with the file name). Quoting form [JLS specification -section 1.2. Example Programs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-1.html#jls-1.2):

> *Most of the example programs given in the text are ready to be executed and are similar in form to:*

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            System.out.print(i == 0 ? args[i] : " " + args[i]);
        System.out.println();
    } 
}
```

> *On a machine with the Oracle JDK installed, this class, stored in the file Test.java, can be compiled and executed by giving the commands:*

```
javac Test.java 
java Test Hello, world.
```

> *producing the output:*

```
Hello, world.
```

The JLS uses programs where top level classes are not public. And I am able to run the above example as it is described above. I have used a filename named `AAA.java` though it produces a `Test.class` when compiled.

Comment: Hmmm I don't know if something went wrong as now I think after compilation classes were not getting updated and that's because issue raised. I had a thought similar to you but some accepted answer at stackoverflow misguided me. So your answer gets accepted. Thanks for asking me to try again and again.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't get the exception when you execute java Class2. I just tried it and it worked:

```
package tests;

class Class1 {
}

class Class2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Up and running");
    }
}
```

In the command line console:

```
java tests.Class2
Up and running
```